# How to use an ajax modal popup and consume a value from a link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I've read a few articles regarding getting values back from a modal popup in an ASP .NET page, but they all seem to use JavaScript to accomplish this which isn't really want I want to do if possible.

I have a web user control which has a repeater that I populate from a list into a table. Each row has a link button which has a redirect url with a value as a query string.

Then I have another web user control which is just a link button with a panel and the repeater web user control that once clicked shows the actual modal popup.

Is it possible to get a value from the web user control once the link button on the repeater is clicked without having to redirect to the same page? I basically want to click on the link, show the modal and once closed, want to access the value.

I'm populating the repeater with the links as follows:

```
        string linkUrl = "";
        string action = "";
        if (Request.QueryString["action"] != null)
        {
            action = Request.QueryString["action"];
            switch (action)
            {
                case "SetupCompany":
                    {
                        linkUrl = "<a href=CreateCompanies.aspx?companyId=";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ViewCompany":
                    {
                        linkUrl = "<a href=ViewCompany.aspx?companyId=";
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        CompaniesBusinessManager mgr = new CompaniesBusinessManager();
        var companies = mgr.GetCompanies(txtCompanyName.Text, txtRegistrationNumber.Text);
        if (linkUrl != "")
        {
            foreach (var c in companies)
            {
                c.Name = linkUrl + c.Id.ToString() + "&action=" + action + ">" + c.Name + "</a>";

            }
        }
        rptrCompanies.DataSource = companies;
        rptrCompanies.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want the page to be redirected, you will need to use javascript. 
There is now way you can pass values from different controls without going back to the server.

In case you keep it without the javascript:

I think you need to pass values from one user control to another. I used to accomplish this by firing reachable events between them.

For example:

in your parent view:

```
<uc:YourUserControl runat="server" ID="UserControl_Test" 
        OnYourCustomAction="UserControl_YourUserControl_YourCustomAction" />
```

In your user control:

```
 public event EventHandler<CustomActionEventArgs> YourCustomAction;
```

also in the same user control create a public trigger method to be access from others usercontrols

```
public void TriggerCustomActoinEvent(CustomActionEventArgs EventArgs)
    {
      if (this.YourCustomAction!= null)
      {
        this.YourCustomAction(this, EventArgs);
      }
    }
```

Hope this help, in on my way to home this was from my mind!

Comment: I ended up bubbling events to the main page. This required a bit of ViewState logic to work around the postback issues. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Without a page postback or JavaScript it not really possible. If you are using modal popups you are already using JS, so why not just get the value in JS? You could setup an event handler for all repeater buttons and if they are loaded via ajax use something like this to attach the event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.repeaterButton', function(e) {
    var valueOfBtnClicked = $(this).val();
    // Do something else
});
```